# Get individual HSL values from hex with SASS

Tags: sass

I want to programmatically adjust styles based on the individual HSL values of a color. Specifically, if a background color is sufficiently dark, then I want to automatically change the text color to white, and vice versa.

The pseudo-code I am trying to achieve is something like,

```
@mixin text-color($color)
    if lightness of $color > 127
        color: #000
    else
        color: #fff
```

Mixin usage:

```
.something {
    background-color: $blue;
    @include text-color($blue);
}
```

Is this possible? Can I break up a color into individual H, S, and L values with SASS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in [lightness function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/color#lightness) which returns the HSL lightness of $color as a number between 0% and 100%.

```
$blue: blue;

@mixin text-color($color) {
  color: if(lightness($color) > 50%, #000, #fff);
}

.something {
  background-color: $blue;
  @include text-color($blue);
}
```

Also, note that you could use a function instead, so you won't be limited to the `color` property only.

```
$blue: blue;

@function text-color($color) {
  @if lightness($color) > 50% {
    @return #000;
  } @else {
    @return #fff;
  }
}

.something {
  background-color: $blue;
  color: text-color($blue);
}
```

Comment: perfect. thanks. i think i was conflating lightness and lighten because i'm pretty sure i was looking at the docs for this but obviously it didnt click.